# Getting profile details of other linkedin users using Api in python

Tags: python-3.x, linkedin-api

The code bellow, prints my account details, but I want it to print other users account dteails, I want to input url of their profile, and then get the details, please let me know if its possible.

```
from linkedin import linkedin
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token='AQUQFzjlCQMv9ptjK4EdYzDKd_3eNoiWTBRpIIv1al-zyigxxE6uH9NgLz4oHVWfddsOsbo8eFd4O9LGe27SnB4b_ouo_Rah7v_c9u4EpKvyVgjGS8oheRiXIcAu0s3WEHzH_QuMcJH-y9ss8A4dboItWxiMoGzO9bNvvUDbzh4Ucr7kqiwgMF-sk0upsxt2a8mGN5tKlgn3LaTjCrAv3ZDBLe91Z_EWbWwZQUI95VLzNdxMTuga1cdy7j3NIGpE4Y1oO_jmpYPufDJR9mdGT_V_JVFfkRckHCqAxQdLd3ThSqtVsbNju_MTPiUd7rfjzl6W3Gt30_DwUHFuwmGVcvSBkmeppg')
print(application.get_profile())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
print(application.get_profile(member_url="https://www.linkedin.com/in/houtankhosrownia/",selectors=['id','emailAddress', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'location', 'distance', 'num-connections', 'skills', 'educations']))
```

replacing this statement with the:

```
print(application.get_profile())
```

Works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you will have access to the linkedin API for other users, as that is where they make their break and butter.

Your best bet would be to use some sort of web scraper. I would recommend scrapy, and I would recommend adhering to the websites web scraping policies which can be found at linkedin.com/robots.txt.

Best of luck